# How to figure out the latest version of a table in the 'recyclebin' section of PL-SQL developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, plsql, plsql-developer

There are three tables with the same name `Pantea` in my `recyclebin`  section of `pl-sql developer` and I don't know how to find the one that had been dropped the last (I mean the last version of the table).

[image]

I can not `restore` all of them cause there can not be tables with the same name in tables section and I can not see the `properties` of the tables in recyclebin either . What is the best way to find the latest version of a table in recyclebin?

Important thing is that think about a situation in which the table has nearly more than 300 columns and it's not a good solution to restore the tables one by one to check whether it's the latest one . I want to know if there is a solution that for one hundred percent returns the latest version of the table from the recyclebin.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can't you just restore one of the three, check if it's OK and then `DROP` it if not? If it's not OK, then maybe you could `TRUNCATE` it so it doesn't reappear in the recycle bin? Warning: I am not familiar with the recycle bin in this context nor how it works - have only looked at allroundautomations' PL/SQL Developer product once and that was a long time ago!

Comment: @Vérace In this scenario I'm familiar with the structure of the table. I'm actually asking this for situation in which the table has  , for instance nearly 300 columns and you want to make sure that by doing the right thing , you have access to the latest version of the table.

Comment: @Vérace I have just edited my question and added a note regarding this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DROPTIME` and `DROPSCN` columns in the [DBA_RECYCLEBIN](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/statviews_4201.htm#REFRN23342) view clearly show when the object was dropped. Stop relying on a simplified GUI.

Comment: Thanks for your brilliant answer . I did not know that .Just a question . How can we restore the table ? cause according to this table "User Recyclebin" we can see the drop date but how can find out which table to restore?? See , we find the record that has the latest drop date , but how do you restore the table??

Comment: @PanteaTourang A specific version of the table can be recovered by referencing the `BIN$...` name of that table as `FLASHBACK TABLE BIN$... TO BEFORE DROP;`

Comment: @PanteaTourang maybe suggest this on the [Allround Automations forum](http://forums.allroundautomations.com/ubb/ubbthreads.php?ubb=postlist&Board=3&page=1) :)